# Add a Zooming Effect On CollectionView Cell In iOS

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

i Want to set a animation like as this link [Avtar Animation library from GitHub](http://code4app.net/ios/Click-to-zoom-in-the-image/52735f7c6803fa954d000000)

on my custom collection view cell when an image was select then it was zoom in the present view. If it was possible then give me solution.n also i code for it like as

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UIImageView *imageview=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
NSString *img2=[self.imagesa objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
imageview.image=[UIImage imageNamed:img2];
[SJAvatarBrowser showImage:imageview];
}
```

But it was not working.and when i put a gesture on my collection view custom cell then 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'invalid nib registered for identifier (CellIdentifier) - nib must contain exactly one top level object which must be a UICollectionReusableView instance'

Comment: you do realize that you are using didDeselectItemAtIndexPath, did you mean it to be didSelectItemAtIndexPath?

Comment: MDB983 I replace that then also it is not working.